# Is there a difference between using .get() and the -> operator?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am doing some studying for a C++ test and one of the questions is as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<Rectangle> rec = std::make_unique<Rectangle>(0, 0, 15, 15);

// why must we use rec.get()->?
rec.get()->setWidth(30);
rec.get()->draw();
```

What I am wondering is why do we need the `.get()` here? Would this be the same if I omitted the `.get()`, like this:

```
rec->setWidth(30);
rec->draw();
```

Comment: I suspect whoever wrote the question was thinking “As opposed to `rec.setWidth()`” and simply wasn’t aware that `unique_ptr` implements `operator->`. In my experience _most_ programming tests are at least a bit crap.

Comment: One could argue to use .get() with smart pointers and -> for the (increasingly rare) cases with raw pointers, so this separation is visible in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*), use of the `->` operator is *equivalent* to using the `get()` function (case 2 in the quote below):

> typename std::add_lvalue_reference::type operator*() const; (1)
>   pointer operator->() const noexcept; (2)
>   **Return value**
>    1) Returns the object owned by *this, equivalent to *get().
>   2) Returns a pointer to the object owned by *this, i.e. get().

Further, and by way of example (though one should never rely on *specific* implementations of the STL), the definitions of `std::unique_ptr::get()` and its 'equivalent' `->` operator in the Visual Studio (MSVC) version of the `<memory>` header are **identical**:

```cpp
    _NODISCARD pointer get() const noexcept {
        return _Mypair._Myval2;
    }
    _NODISCARD pointer operator->() const noexcept {
        return _Mypair._Myval2;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`.get()` is not necessary in your case as `rec->draw()` will de-reference the underlying pointer and therefore you can use unique pointers with the same syntax as raw pointers. `.get()` is necessary when you need to pass your unique pointer to a function that takes a raw pointer as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointers are designed to act like raw pointers in most aspects, other than memory management. That way they are easy to adopt with minimal changes. In particular, they are designed to be dereferenced using the same syntax as raw pointers. That means you can use `rec->` instead of `rec.get()->`, and `*rec` instead of `*(rec.get())`.